# Font import not working on IE10

Tags: css, internet-explorer, fonts, font-face

For a client I got to change the font use on an old app for work...
It work very well for other browser but it didn't on Internet Explorer (current version is 10)...

I'd found a lot of thing on the net about it, but I still got the problem ...
Sorry if I missed the answer :(

Here is my code to import the font :

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Din';
    src: url('../fonts/din/DINPro.eot');
    src: url('../fonts/din/DINPro.otf') format('truetype'),
    url('../fonts/din/DINPro.woff') format('woff'),
    url('../fonts/din/DINPro.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('../fonts/din/DINPro.svg#QuadrantaBold') format('svg');
    font-weight:400;
    font-style:normal;
}
```

Sorry for all the spelling mistakes

Comment: Maybe is the conversion of the EOT files. It happens sometimes. The conversion is not appropiate and IE trash it.

Comment: You point maybe something, the client only give the .OTF file, is that the problem ?

Comment: check your source path...it should be work in IE10

Comment: @Tibaldo did you say that in IE the only font file that is loaded is the .OTF ? Check the paths as abidkhanweb said.

Comment: It work on other browser so why it wouldn't for IE if it's the path ? Anyway, i check it just in case and they are fine ... 
@MarcosPérezGude no i wanted to say that in the folder "fonts" > "din" there is only the .otf in, 
there isn't .eot etc ...

Comment: So that's your problem . Why did you include the EOT, TTF, WOFF, SVG files if you haven't got it? This will produce you a lot of compatibility errors. To IE you need EOT file. Otherwise never works. You can convert a TTF to all formats here: http://www.font2web.com/

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude Thank you for your answer, i will try this immediatly !

Comment: Tell me if it's working when you finish :)

Comment: Well it work perfectly ! Thank again for your helps guys and for the font2web it's very helpfull !
Thank again @MarcosPérezGude

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As we talk in comments, you need to convert the font in all formats that you need and then include it in the code (you have the complete code yet, so you only need to convert and upload the files).

I recommend:

http://font2web.com

IE browser needs EOT files.